# Null pointer exception in client side when calling a web service method in JBoss 5

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, jboss5.x

I am getting null pointer exception in client when calling ParentService' process method from client. But in server log no exception is there. 
I am using server side handler. The request is comming to handler and after completing the ParentHandler's handleMessage method it's coming back to client with NPE.

**Client Stacktrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
at $Proxy30.service(Unknown Source)
```

**Server Codes**

**Service Class:**

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
@HandlerChain(file = "ParentServiceHandler.xml")
public interface ParentService {
  @WebMethod
  public Parent process(Parent parent);
}
```

**Implementation class:**

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.practise.ws.ParentService")
public class ParentServiceImp implements ParentService {
  @Resource 
  private WebServiceContext context;
  @Override
  public Parent process(Parent parent) {
    System.out.println("Process calling---------------");
    return parent;
  }
}
```

**Handler class:**

```
public class ParentHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
  @Override
  public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext mc) {
    try{
      Boolean flag = (Boolean)mc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
      if(!flag){
        SOAPMessage soapMsg = mc.getMessage();  
        System.out.println("MESSAGE: " + soapMsg);
        soapMsg.writeTo(System.out);
      }
      return true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
    return Collections.emptySet();
  }

  @Override
  public void close(MessageContext mc) {}

  @Override
  public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext mc) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**ParentServiceHandler.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <handler-chain>
    <handler>
      <handler-name>ServiceSOAPHandler</handler-name>
      <handler-class>com.practise.handler.ParentHandler</handler-class>
    </handler>
  </handler-chain>
</handler-chains>
```

**sun-jaxws.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
  <endpoint name="ParentChild" implementation="com.practise.ws.ParentChildImp"
        url-pattern="/parentWs" />
</endpoints>
```

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>
    com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ParentChild</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ParentChild</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/parentWs</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Client code:**

```
public class WebServiceClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ParentServiceImpService service = new ParentServiceImpService();
    ParentService objService = (ParentService) service.getParentChildImpPort();
    ChildA child =new ChildA();
    child.setStrParent("Parent");
    child.setStrChildA("Child");
    objService.process(child);
  }
}
```

But when I am sending blank child object then it's working properly. 
    **objService.process(new ChildA());**

**Please help me**.

Comment: Possibility is :if(!flag), change to if(flag.booleanValue()), if this is not helping then try removing @SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
@HandlerChain(file = "ParentServiceHandler.xml"), and test it.

Comment: Hi Jayaram, Thank you for your reply. I tried  if(flag.booleanValue()) and removing SOAPBinding annotations also but it's not working. When I removed HandlerChain it's working but I need handler to get the soap message.

Comment: Great. Basically was looking at narrow down the issue, please remove your @HandlerChain, and try with <ws:handlers><ref bean="soapLogHandler"/></ws:handlers> inside your <ws:service>, you can chain any number of handlers.As some days back also I faced the same issue, after replacing it worked fine for me

Comment: My Mistake I was under impression that you are creating this in spring way..Please follow these references http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.2/docs/handlers.html http://blog.lebrijo.com/jax-ws-handler-chain-messages-interceptor/

Comment: Thanks Jayaram I will check and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Jayaram, I check the articles. I updated my config files also. But still not working. Please help me.

Comment: I am getting below error, are they similar or its totally different issue :

`03-08-2015 12:32:00,358 SEVERE [com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1] (pool-2183-thread-1) SAAJ0304: InputStream does not represent a valid SOAP 1.1 Message
03-08-2015 12:32:00,537 ERROR [stderr] (pool-2183-thread-1) javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: org.switchyard.HandlerException: java.lang.NullPointerException`